# How to increase city strength?

Tags: civilization-6, civilization-6-rise-and-fall

What factors can increase or decrease the combat strength of a city (both standard and ranged strength)?

Known methods,

- Building walls in the city.
- Having a garrisoned unit.
- Applying the Bastions policy card.

*If there are expansion specific methods I would be pleased to know those as well.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between the [wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/City_combat_(Civ5)) and a [civfanatics](https://forums.civfanatics.com/threads/city-strength.619428/) post here's what I gathered,

- **Era**: Each era has a *base city strength* Ancient being around 10 and Modern being somewhere around 50-60.
- **Terrain**: Just like in Civilization 5, being constructed on a hill provides additional combat strength for the city. Additionally, settling on a river can increase city combat strength.
- **Population**: More population means more city strength.
- **Buildings**: Walls, Castles, Arsenals, and Military Bases all increase the city's combat strength.
- **Garrison**: A land unit in the city will increase the city's combat strength.
- **Districts**: Each district contributes to the city's combat strength.
- **Palace**: The capital's Palace increases city combat strength.
- **City-States**: If the city is a city-state, the most number of envoys (up to 6) by a single player contributes to the city-state's combat strength.
- **Difficulty**: The difficulty level you are playing on can also contribute to a city's combat strength.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the above, the Castellon governor Victor in the *Rise and Fall* expansion provides

- +5 combat strength once established in a city
- an additional Ranged Strike per turn as a promotion